Why doesn't MLB The Show have all levels of MiLB?
For those of you who aren't huge baseball fans like me, there are actually four levels of minor league baseball: (You can skip this if you want, but this is for extra context so you'll understand the terminology I use)
Class-A: This is generally where new draft picks are sent after being signed.
High-A: Class-A but for more developed players. This level still resembles high-school or college baseball, as the players haven't yet been humbled by the demanding conditions of pro baseball.
Double-A: Lowest league featured in MLB The Show. Getting here IRL is actually a massive challenge. This is also the first level that actually resembles real professional baseball, as the pitchers throw faster here and some of them are former major leaguers sent down for rehab or training. Players are just better in general.
Triple-A: Last stop before MLB. Pitchers here generally throw at Major League speeds with some exceptions. Umpires are slightly stricter than Double-A and don't tolerate disrespect like they may have in Class-A or High-A. Players in Triple-A look like they are about ready to be MLB players and some of them are only there due to a full roster.

In MLB The Show Franchise mode, it's an option to send your players down to Class-A, but doing so will make them not play and it is not an option to play as a class-A team, but you can play as Double-A and Triple-A. The interesting thing is though, you can send players to Class-A and some of a team's Class-A roster is included but not all of it. It's not like the team isn't coded into the game because if you send someone to Class-A and go to transactions it will say "Sent Joe Random down from Double-A Amarillo to Class-A Hillsboro". (Hillsboro is the High-A/Class-A Affiliate of the Arizona Diamondbacks).
My question is why exactly would they have the teams 'in the game' but you cannot play as them?

If I was a wagering guy, I'd say there probably isn't a big enough playerbase that plays Franchise Mode or RTTS with a big focus on the minors to make it worth the time commitment. From what I can gleam, SDS hasn't made an official comment on why, so we can only speculate. To play devil's advocate, I don't know why they'd want to do this, when SDS could better spend their time on other aspects of the game.

@Hoppeduppeanut I understand, and those aren't my focuses anyways. I'm just wondering why they would bother putting the team names in the game andd not use them.
